# How to make date picker display a user specific date (for a birthday for example)

Tags: ios, swiftui, datepicker, swiftui-form

I am trying to implement a date-picker in a form in swiftui. It should display the birthday as the user select it.
Here you can find most of my code.
I have no idea how to do this please help.

Thank you so much in advance.

```
import SwiftUI


struct DetailView: View {
    
    var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .long
        return formatter
    }
    
    @ObservedObject var dm : DataManager
    var bimba : ContactModel
    
    
    @State var isSharePresented = false
    @State var isAlertPresented = false
    @State var isAddPresented = false
    @State var nome : String = ""
    @State var birthDate = Date()
    
    
    
    var items : [Any] {
        return [bimba.realImage, bimba.nome]
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
          //  Color.blue
            VStack {
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        VStack {
                            Spacer()
                                .padding()
                            Form {
                                
                                Section {
                                    
                                    HStack {
                                        Text(loc("RAZ"))

                                        Spacer()
                                        Text(bimba.razza)
                                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                            .font(.callout)
                                    }
                                    
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("Sesso")

                                        Spacer()
                                        Text(bimba.gender)
                                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                            .font(.callout)
                                
                                    }
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("Peso")

                                        Spacer()
                                        Text(bimba.peso)
                                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                            .font(.callout)
                                        Text("kg")
                                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                    }
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("Età")
                                        Spacer()
                                        Text(bimba.bday)
                                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                            .font(.callout)
                                        Text("Anni")
                                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                    }
                                    
                                    DatePicker("Birthdate", selection: $birthDate, in: ...Date(), displayedComponents: .date)
                                        .accentColor(Color.gray)
                                    
                                }
                                
                                Section {
                                    
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("Mantello")
                                        Spacer()
                                        Text(bimba.mantello)
                                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                            .font(.callout)
                                    }
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("Colore")
                                        Spacer()
                                        Text(bimba.colore)
                                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                            .font(.callout)
                                    }
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("Pelo")
                                        Spacer()
                                        Text(bimba.pelo)
                                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                            .font(.callout)
                                    }
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("Orecchie")
                                        Spacer()
                                        Text(bimba.orecchie)
                                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                            .font(.callout)
                                    }
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("Coda")
                                        Spacer()
                                        Text(bimba.coda)
                                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                            .font(.callout)
                                    }
                                    
                                    
                                }
                                
                                Section {
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("Chip No")
                                        
                                        Spacer()
                                        Text(bimba.chip)
                                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                            .font(.callout)
                                    }
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("Nome Pedigree")
                                        
                                        Spacer()
                                        Text(bimba.nomePedig)
                                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                            .font(.callout)
                                    }
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("Codice ENCI")
                                        
                                        Spacer()
                                        Text(bimba.codiceEnci)
                                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                            .font(.callout)
                                    }
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("Data Registrazione")
                                        
                                        Spacer()
                                        Text(bimba.regisDate)
                                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                            .font(.callout)
                                    }
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("ID No")
                                        
                                        Spacer()
                                        Text(bimba.codiceId)
                                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                            .font(.callout)
                                    }

                                }
                                Section {
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("Altro")
                                        
                                        Spacer()
                                        Text(bimba.altroInfo)
                                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                            .font(.callout)
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }.padding(.bottom, -80)
                }.background(
                    Text(bimba.nome)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .offset(x: 0, y: -50))
                
                .background(
                    Text(bimba.nick)
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    //       .offset(x: 0, y: -50))
                )
                .offset(x: 0, y: -80)
                
                .background(
                    Image(uiImage: bimba.realImage)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .frame(width: 180, height: 180)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                        .offset(x: 0, y: 0)
                        .shadow(radius: 6)
                        .padding(.bottom, 530))
                Spacer()
                
                // .navigationBarTitle(Text(bimba.nome), displayMode: .large)
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        editButton.padding(.horizontal, 16).offset(x: 0, y: -5)
                        Spacer()
                        shareButton.padding(.horizontal, 16).offset(x: 0, y: -5)
                    }.frame(height: 44)
                }
                .frame(height: 34)
                
            }
        }
        //  .navigationBarTitle(Text(bimba.nome), displayMode: .large)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code to my sample project and the DatePicker worked correctly - on the first screen I tapped on date view with the date 29.04.2020, it showed me DatePicker view (second screen) with the correct date, then I changed the date to 29.01.2021 (third screen) and after DatePicker view dismiss the date was correct (fourth screen). Where is the problem? Maybe I missed something

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you create the birthday object as Date(), it assigns the exact date and time every time the DetailView rerenders. If you have the birthday of user stored in any place, you need to call that information in your form.

Edit:

```
var birthdayOfUser = Date().addingTimeInterval(24.0 * 3600) // you add time intervals as seconds

DatePicker("Birthdate", selection: $birthdayOfUser, in: ...Date(), displayedComponents: .date)
.accentColor(Color.gray)
```

This example binds the tomorrow as the day which DatePicker will show. All you need to do is bind the stored birthday of user like this.

By the way this birthday example is in future and is not valid. I just wanted to show a different Date object other than exact time.

Comment: Add some code snippet for better understanding of answer.